# How to count and record number duplicates in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I need to count and record how many times each item is duplicated. For example the following array:

```
let arr = [
  {item:"pen"},
  {item:"book"},
  {item:"pen"}
];
```

This should be returned:

```
let arr = [
  {item:"pen", found: 2},
  {item:"book", found: 1},
  {item:"pen", found: 2}
]
```

The attribute "found" should indicate how many times an item appears in the array.

Comment: Can you share with us what have you tried so far? Or what is the approach you are thinking of using?

Comment: @vol7ron it would be e.g {item:"book", found: 1}

Comment: @Harry yes, I should have improved the comment. The post reqds “count and record how many times each item is duplicated” which suggested that the book found:1 was an error or the text was wrong. You just want a count, not a count of duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use two loop one for iteration one for filter i.e

```
arr.forEach(item => {
  item.found = arr.filter(filterObject => filterObject.item == item.item).length;
})
```

Comment: @Harry unless filter is memoized, this is extremely inefficient. Please don’t use that approach

Comment: agree with @vol7ron i think better approch will be :
if(item. found){
let filterd = arr.filter(filterObject => filterObject.item == item.item); filterd.forEach(filterdItem => { filterdItem.found = filterd.length})

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

I have looped the array 2 times and found the duplicate elements, then incremented the new `found` value.

```js
let arr = [
  {item:"pen"},
  {item:"book"},
  {item:"pen"}
];

var newArr = [];

arr.forEach(function(res){
  res.found = 0;
  arr.forEach(function(data){
    if(res.item === data.item){
      res.found++;
    }
  });
  newArr.push(res);
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: There are two things that are not there in this answer as asked by the question: 1. The result wont be in the format provided by the question. 2. There is no check for the repeated items so, this code isn't efficient enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin this cat, some more efficient and some more maintainable.  Here's a little bit of both (not the most efficient nor maintainable), which should be easy to follow:

```js
let arr = [
  {item:"pen"},
  {item:"book"},
  {item:"pen"}
];

let found = {};

// Find repeated objects
arr.forEach((obj,i)=>{
  found[obj.item]=found[obj.item]||[];
  found[obj.item].push(i)
})

// Apply totals to original objects
Object.values(found).forEach(indexes=>
  indexes.forEach(index=>arr[index].found = indexes.length)
);

console.log(arr);
```